# NLog.Mongo and latest mongoDB C# driver not working

Tags: c#, mongodb, nlog

nLog does not work when I upgrade my project to the latest mongoDB Driver:

```
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NLog.Mongo.MongoTarget' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.9.2.235, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
at NLog.Mongo.MongoTarget..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NLog.Mongo.MongoTarget..ctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
 at NLog.Internal.FactoryHelper.CreateInstance(Type t)
```

It logs nothing. I am using a mongoDB target for nLog. I already posted an issue (https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/issues/7). But maybe there is a way to solve it on my own.

Any suggestions?

The target works with official mongoDB driver versions before 1.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an Assembly binding to your web.config

```
  <runtime>
       <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Driver" publicKeyToken="f686731cfb9cc103" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.10.0.62" newVersion="1.10.0.62" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MongoDB.Bson" publicKeyToken="f686731cfb9cc103" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.10.0.62" newVersion="1.10.0.62" />
      </dependentAssembly>

  </runtime>
```

Comment: Is this done manually in the web.config or can this be done via the GUI